# Start two springboot apps in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-boot

Is it possible to start two spring boot applications in eclipse, in the same workspace in the same time? How can i set two different ports for that two spring boot applications?

Comment: YES. Change the default port as explained below (server.port property) and just run it. I have several apps running together at the same time (a microsevices application) and it works perfect

Comment: Hii My services is using WXS(IBM Websphere as server) for multiple applications how can I configure WXS to get them running simaltaneously?

Answer (score 6):

**Yes**. It is possible to run two spring boot apps same time in the same `workspace` in `eclipse`. This is possible because each spring boot app comes with an `embedded tomcat server` and we have to make sure that each of them  uses a different port number respectively.

In each spring boot application, add `application.properties` file in `src/main/resources` folder. To override the default `8080` port, you have to use [server.port](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-change-the-http-port) property in the `application.properties` file. Make sure you set different port in each of the application. For example, set `server.port=8888` in one application and `server.port=9999` in another application, so that app1 will run on 8888 port and app2 will run on 9999 port.

To scan for a free port (using OS natives to prevent clashes) use [server.port=0](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-user-a-random-unassigned-http-port).

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the port that the embedded instance of `tomcat` runs on by putting `server.port=[port number here]` in your `application.properties`. If you want `tomcat` to run on a random port put `server.port=0` in `application.properties`.

I'm not sure about running two instances in the same workspace, I've never tried. But if you try to deploy and both `tomcat` instances are trying to run on the same port you will get 'tomcat connector in a failed state'.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Go to **/src/main/resources/application.properties**
2. Add **server.port= PortNo**(for example server.port=8081 in first app's application.properties and server.port=8082 in second app's application.properties)
3. Right-click on each application one by one and **Run As Spring Boot App**
4. Go the browser and hit **localhost:8081** for the first app and **localhost:8082** for the second app, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change the port using argument -Dserver.port=XXXX to override the properties value in Run Configuration windows, each time you launch the app. Keep in mind you must change on each launch to avoid a port collision.